# re-building filename with zsh script using regex

Tags: files, zsh

I download files with the pattern

```
Konto_12334567890-Auszug_YYYY_00MM.pdf
```

and want to save it in a path

```
.../Belege YYYY/Belege YYYY MM/Kontoauszug.pdf
```

The problem is how to extract the year YYYY and the month MM from the origin filename and put it into the folder names of the new filename's path.

I've got the filename (without path) in a variable called `$filename`. I have another variable, `$dest` for the path and `$filename_new` for the new filename (in this case: constantly `Kontoauszug`).

My first thought was: get rid of all content before and including `Auszug_` and get the first four digits into one variable (`$year`) and the last two digits before `.pdf` into another (`$month`). There maybe better solutions...

So I can build the path like this:

```
DEST="/Users/Belege/Belege $year/Belege $year $month/"
```

I just have to get `$year` and `$month` filled.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is to move them via `zmv` and a helper function, e.g.

```
dtmv () {                                                                     
    mkdir -p -- $2:h && mv -- $@
}
autoload zmv
zmv -n -P dtmv 'Konto_12334567890-Auszug_(*)_00(*).pdf' '/Users/Belege_$1/Belege_$1_$2/Kontoauszug.pdf'
```

The `(*)`s create back references that can be used in the second parameter as `$1`, `$2` etc.
Here `zmv` with `-P` executes the function `dtmv` instead of `mv`. The function creates the directory and then moves the file to the newly created directory. For each file, it is passed the original and replacement file.

*Note* that `-n` stands for *dry-run* so the above will only print the commands to be run. Remove the `-n` to actually run the command. I also advise against using filenames with spaces but if you insist on having them replace all underscores with spaces:

```
zmv -n -P dtmv 'Konto_12334567890-Auszug_(*)_00(*).pdf' '/Users/Belege $1/Belege $1 $2/Kontoauszug.pdf'
```

---

If, for some reason, you must use variables, there are several ways to do it. Since filenames have a fixed length and match the same pattern I'd personally use substrings e.g.

```
year=${filename: -13:-9}
month=${filename: -6:-4}
```

Note the space between the first colon `:` and the minus `-`
Another way is to split the string on `_` (after removing the extension with `:r`) so the year is the 3rd element and the month is the 4th element less the first two chars:

```
year=${${(s[_])filename:r}[3]}
month=${${${(s[_])name:r}[4]}:2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file names are always how you show and that the YYYY and MM are numbers, you can do something like this:

```
filename=Konto_12334567890-Auszug_2022_0005.pdf     
year=$(cut -d_ -f3 <<<"$filename")
month=$(cut -d_ -f4 <<<"$filename" | sed -e 's/^00//' -e  's/.pdf$//')
mv -- "$filename" "/Users/Belege/Belege $year/Belege $year $month/"
```

However, I cannot stress enough how bad an idea it is to have paths and file names with spaces. Those will only make any future work you do with the files more complicated. So I strongly urge you to do something like this instead:

```
mv -- "$filename" "/Users/Belege/Belege_$year/Belege_${year}_$month/"
```

Comment: I did the following:

filename=$f:t

year_in_filename=$(cut -d_ -f3 <<<"$filename")
month_in_filename=$(cut -d_ -f4 <<<"$filename" | sed -e 's/^00//' -e  's/.pdf$//')

if [[ $f == *"Konto_1096216427-Auszug"* ]] 
then DEST="/Users/ralf/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Company/Company Buchführung/Company Belege/Belege $year_in_filename/Belege $year_in_filename $month_in_filename/"
filename_new="Kontoauszugtest.pdf"

Comment: @Ralf sorry, I don't understand. Did it work or not?

Comment: I did the following - but does not work.

filename=$f:t
year_in_filename=$(cut -d_ -f3 <<<"$filename")
month_in_filename=$(cut -d_ -f4 <<<"$filename" | sed -e 's/^00//' -e  's/.pdf$//')

if [[ $f == *"Konto_0000000000-Auszug"* ]] 
then DEST="/Users/ralf/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Company/Company Buchführung/Company Belege/Belege $year_in_filename/Belege $year_in_filename $month_in_filename/"
filename_new="Kontoauszugtest.pdf"
mv $f "$DEST/$filename_new.pdf"
fi

Filename of tested file to move: "Konto_0000000000-Auszug_2022_0012.PDF"

What's wrong?

Comment: @Ralf I can't read that. Please edit your question and explain what you did and how it failed. Note that if your files are actually `.PDF` and not `.pdf` then you need to use `.PDF` wherever I have used `.pdf`. This is why I asked you to show us the _actual_ file name. Your question has `.pdf`.

Comment: OMG it was PDF vs. pdf. Thanks for helping me!!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the more generic question as to how to extract YYYY and MM in `Konto_12334567890-Auszug_YYYY_00MM.pdf`, you could do:

```
set -o extendedglob
file='Konto_12334567890-Auszug_YYYY_00MM.pdf'
if [[ $file = (#b)*_(<1900-2100>)_00(<1-12>).pdf ]]; then
  year=$match[1] month=$match[2]
fi
```

`<1-12>` matches on any sequence of decimal digit that represents a number in the range 1 to 12 (so including 1, 01, 0000000001). `<->` matches and sequence of one or more decimal digits, same as extendedglob `[0-9]##`.

`(#b)` enables `b`ack references, so the parts inside `(...)` are available in `$match`.